# How to create a site-search in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I started creating own Symfony bundles some weeks ago. I've created some entities with all the stuff around (also used the Doctrine CRUD-command), made some twig extensions and created new templates.

Now I wanted to implement a Search Form in my Project. **Are there some simlpe ways or some predefined Search-Bundles, which I can use in my Project?**

I created my search-form manually (form without an entity). Then form is submitted via GET and the Results (selcted from the Entities in the Controller with a repository-search) are shown below the search form on the same page.

Now I think, that it isn't good to have a very long URL, because of the Fields in the Form. I could go further and submit e.g. a `<select>` list with multiple entries selected and the URL would even be longer.

Would it be a good choice to submit the Form via POST, "cut" the unnecessary "URL-Array-Elements" (+make the Query-Items more readable for humans) and redirect to the URL with the queries for showing the results?

Edited: **Are there any simple ways, how I can create a specific search form or entity-filter which I can use for custom entities?** I like to use/create a function, where I can insert the entity, define the search-tags/filters and output a search-form? Has anyone created/used such search/filter-functions?

Comment: There is a SearchBundle in Symfony, but that integrates with google-search for site wide searching. Is that what you want?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/search/introduction.html

Or do you mean an easy way to make specific search forms to search/filter your custom entities?

Comment: thanks for the link of the Bundle, I'm pretty sure that I can use it. But what I wanted is an easy way to make search-forms/filters for entities. Sorry, maybe my definition was a bit poor worded - it was my first question here...

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/samson/filter-bundle
My company made this bundle, it allows creation of filters, maybe this is what you need?

Comment: Hi Eric, i will definitely have a look at your bundle. :)  Are there any documentation-files about the installation, configuration and use?